# Request is malformed or invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access the Microsoft Graph API to read user's email but I am having issue of calling the Microsoft Graph API service.

As of now, I can authenticate the user, but having issue to get the token to access the Graph API.

I've tried to understand the documentation from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp)

My understanding of the flow is :

```
1) Redirect user to Microsoft Identity Platform for authentication
2) For authorization, you need to provide scopes, tenantId, clientId, clientSecert and authorization code.
3) Access Graph API
```

This is my controller to handle the microsoft login and access the Graph API :

```
public IActionResult MicrosoftLogin()
        {
            // Redirect user to Microsoft Identity Platform for authentication
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home/MicrosoftCallback" }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
```

And the callback :

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> MicrosoftCallback()
        {
            try
            {

                var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

                // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
                // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
                var tenantId = "common";

                // Values from app registration
                var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
                var clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

                var authorizationCode = "AUTH_CODE_FROM_REDIRECT";
  
                // using Azure.Identity;
                var options = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialOptions
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                };

                // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.authorizationcodecredential
                var authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
                    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, authorizationCode, options);

                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);

                var user = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
                var outlookmail = await graphClient.Me.Messages.GetAsync();
                ViewData["user"] = user;
                ViewData["mail"] = outlookmail;
                return View("MicrosoftHome");
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex);
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Also, at the callback, the codes are obtained from the documentation on Authorization Code Provider.
I'm not sure I should replace the scopes, tenantId, clientId, secrets with my own app registered at AAD.If it is, how to obtain the authorization code?

This is my Program.cs file :

```
string[] initialScopes = configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
services
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    //options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = "AppCookie";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyAzureAdScheme";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddCookie("AppCookie")
.AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");

    // Add the required scope for GMail API access
    googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
    googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;

})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure ADD OAuth2 Auth Code flow basically involves two steps

- Getting auth code - during this call, the user will be prompted to authenticate on [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant/common}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant/common%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)
- Getting tokens using the code which is sent in the redirect URI.

See this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) to understand better.

Concerning your question:

`Also, at the callback, the codes are obtained from the documentation on Authorization Code Provider. I'm not sure I should replace the scopes, tenantId, clientId, secrets with my own app registered at AAD.If it is, how to obtain the authorization code?`

Yes, you need to replace the tenantId, clientId, clientSecret.

As for authorization code it will be sent as a parameter to the callback handler. If you set `response_mode=query` the the code will be sent to call back as query parameter. If you your callback URL is http://localhost:300 then it will be called with `http://localhost? code=AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGBCmLdgfSTLEMPGYuNHSUYBrq...&state=1234567`

I suggest you first read through [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) the check this [sample code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp).